# qtip2 tooltip on link floating on the screen

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, qtip2

I have a link to another page in which I have set a qtip2 tooltip. So when you overmouse the link the tooltip is displayed, this is OK, but when you click the link (you haven't performed a mouse out event) and get forward to following screen the tooltip is still displayed, floating on the screen

anybody knows how to avoid this annoying behaviour? thanks is advance

Comment: You could bind a function to the click event of the link which then hides the tooltip.

Comment: finally this has worked for me: $('div.qtip:visible').qtip('hide');

Answer (score 0):

Finally this has worked for me:

```
$('div.qtip:visible').qtip('hide');
```